# Confusion in finding order and degree of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in this question im asked to find order and degree of ode

(y')^2 +5 (y)^1/3 = x

confusion is that i can see order is 1 and degree is 2 ... but if i write eqn as (y')^2 - x = 5 (y^1/3) . then cubing both sides i get order 1 and degree 6 . why is this confusion .i mean while seeing at once its o and deg are different after manipulating algebrically and also answer to this is former . i dont know !!

Also what things need to be taken care of for determining order and degree of any arbitrary ode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cubing both sides, you are changing the degree of the equation. It's exactly the same as if you had a linear equation $$x=1$$ and squared both sides to get $$x^2=1.$$ Any solutions to the original equation are solutions to the new equation, but you may have introduced new solutions by changing the degree. Note in this case, $x=-1$ is also a solution of the new equation, but not of the original equation.

In fact, the same thing happens in the case of the ODE you mention. You have introduced additional solutions (possibly complex) by changing the degree.

Generally, the equation $$LHS^3 = RHS^3$$ is equivalent to the *three* equations

$$ LHS = e^{2k\pi i/3}RHS $$

(for $k=0,1,2$). The "original" equation is only one of these (the case $k=0$).

Comment: Thanks for solution but my main concern is when to stop cubing it i.e when do we know that given ODE degree and order can be directly found without using manipulations like cubing . i mean precisely what should be present in it or what shouldnt be so that it is fit for seeing its degree and order